# Вызвать конструктор через конструктор при композиции

Tags: c++

Код компилируется, но сообщение конструктора `Feather()` не выводится для поля `vector <Feather> feathers;`,
если же брать не вектор, а просто переменную `Feather feather;`, то сообщение выводится. Вопрос: как правильно это провернуть и получить сообщение от конструктора о создании вектора?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Feather
{
public:
    Feather() :length(0)
    {
        cout << "Feather was created" << endl;
    }
private:
    int length;
};

class Bird
{
public:
    Feather feather;
    vector <Feather> feathers;
    Bird() : feather(), feathers(), name("bird")
    {
        cout << "Bird was created" << endl;
    }
private:
    string name;
};

int main()
{
    {
        Bird bird;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете пустой вектор. А пустому вектору не нужно вызывать конструктор вложенного объекта. Поэтому, Вы и не видите сообщений. Хотите увидеть и сообщения от Feather из вектора? Перепишите список инициализации так

```
Bird() : feather(), feathers(100), name("bird")
```

Но в  этом случае, внутри вектора будет сотня элементов типа перо:)

Comment: И 100 сообщений конструктора.

Comment: это специально, что бы было видно наверняка.